# how to use arrayFilters and $push to update a same array field at same time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

model as follow:

```
let gardenmodal = new mongoose.Schema({
    display:{type:Boolean, default:true},
    itemList:[{type:Number,count:Number}]
});

let GardenModel = db.model('GardenModel', gardenmodal);
```

document as follow:

```
{ display: true,
  itemList:
   [ { type: 1, count: 200 },
     { type: 2, count: 81 },
     { type: 3, count: 78 } ],
  _id: 5b2e52144c73cb22fc77b92b,
  __v: 0 }
```

I want to update the element with type =1 to make its num decrease 2 and the element with type =2 to make its num decrease 3, at the same time a new element with its  type=10, count=100, need to push into the itemList, here is my try:

```
let res = await GardenModel.findOneAndUpdate({},{
        $inc:{"itemList.$[elem1].count":-3, "itemList.$[elem2].count" : -2},
        $push:{"itemList":{ type: 10, count: 200 }}
    },{
        arrayFilters:[{"elem1.type":2},{"elem2.type":3}],
        new:true
    });
```

but it works fail:

```
(node:6596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Updating the path 'itemList.$[elem1].count' would create a conflict at 'itemList'
    at H:\node\wcgroup\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:593:63
    at authenticateStragglers (H:\node\wcgroup\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:516:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (H:\node\wcgroup\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:552:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (H:\node\wcgroup\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:309:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (H:\node\wcgroup\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:452:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:279:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:636:20)
```

what should I do?

Comment: Please show your model as well because above code is working

Comment: thanks for your attention. I have add the model at the beginning.

Comment: Your itemList should be like `[{ type:Number, count:Number}]... Then you can easily update it.

Comment: I have modify the model as you say but it is still the error.did you run demo as you say ?

Comment: Yes I ran... What is the error you are getting?

Comment: the error:Updating the path 'itemList.$[elem1].count' would create a conflict at 'itemList'       .....    did your demo as same as mine?

Comment: Please show your updated model... Is there any I can show you my working code? Are you sure you are using 3.6?

Comment: the modified model is at the beginning of the problem. Yes , you can show your code by answer

Comment: Ok... I will be back to you in 2 hours after reaching office and will show you what I have don done

Comment: Your above code is working for me...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet   my mongoose version is 5.1.7, mongodb version 3.6.4. what's your version?

Comment: Same versions...  Did you run this command `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } ).`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I didn't run this command, and is there any connections between the command and the problem?

Comment: try by running this command in mongo shell and hit your query

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have done what you say, but it is just the same error:> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.gardenmodels.update({_id:ObjectId("5b38299cb4546104b086ef9f")},{$inc:{"itemList.$[elem1].count":-2, "itemList.$[elem2].count":-3},$push:{itemList:{itemType:10,count:30}}},{arrayFilters:[{"elem1.itemType":1},{"elem2.itemType":2}]})
WriteResult({
 "nMatched" : 0,
 "nUpserted" : 0,
 "nModified" : 0,
 "writeError" : {
  "code" : 40,
  "errmsg" : "Updating the path 'itemList' would create a conflict at 'itemList'"
 }
})

Comment: You have to run two queries one for `$inc` and one for `$push` that's only the way you can achieve